# Docker push says "name invalid: Nested repositories are not supported."

Tags: docker, quay.io

$ docker push quay.io/kapilqdocker/repo/mcd:v0.0.1

```
The push refers to repository [quay.io/kapilqdocker/repo/mcd]
ac245be5b1f2: Retrying in 1 second
a05521c42d34: Retrying in 1 second
586251520418: Retrying in 2 seconds
48eeec1f62af: Retrying in 2 seconds
5bfa1c2bc41d: Retrying in 4 seconds
name invalid: Nested repositories are not supported. Found: kapilqdocker/repo/mcd
```

Sorry, it could be simple issue. I do not know what mistake is there, I created a repo
quay.io/repository/kapilqdocker/repo

same is the result for
docker push quay.io/repository/kapilqdocker/repo/mcd:v0.0.1

Comment: The format should be docker push dockerUserId/repositoryName:tag

Comment: But this is on quay.io, If i do not specify quay.io, how will it know where to push ?

Comment: Sorry no idea. I thought you were trying to push in dockerhub.

Comment: Anyways thanks for attempting

Answer (score 2):

Ran into the same issue. And later figured out each Image becomes a repo. And that repo would have multiple versions for your application.
Hence, in your case the below should work.

```
docker push quay.io/kapilqdocker/mcd
```